# Is it possible to create a table with a multi-level row using ASP.NET GridView or other control

Tags: asp.net

I'm not sure if I'm using the correct terminology to describe my questions so I created a few mock ups to try to show what I am trying to do.

I have an existing table listing order detail information that looks something like this:
[image]

I have some additional attributes I want to add columns for, but I would like it to appear on a separate line as part of the same row sort of like this:

[image]

The reason I want to add these columns but have them appear on the second line of each row is that I want to display more data in each row  but I don't want to make the row/page wider.

I did some googling for this problem, but I'm not even sure what the standard name for this type of display is so I wasn't able to come up with anything. The closest I found was [this code project link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/MasterDetail.aspx
) which is close to, but not the same thing I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what to call it either (multiline gridview?) but it should be possible.  I would suggest looking at making a grid with a template column and a formview inside the template.  In the rowdatabound event of the grid you write code to bind your form to the row's data.  I have used this technique before on nested grids, it should work with other controls as well.  Might be simpler ways to do it too, not something I have had a need to work out before.

EDIT:
I just saw a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9536089/634223) where someone provided a link to this [article](http://www.dotnetglobe.com/2011/09/rows-and-columns-merging-in-aspnet_03.html).  Not quite what we were talking about here, but very similar.  Thought I would include it here as well for future reference.  To bad it was written 5 months after this question was asked...

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. I'll give that a try